# Exception upon adding a new document to Raven DB Management Studio

Tags: ravendb

When I click on "New Document" in the Raven DB Management Studio, I see the following exception:

[Arg_TargetInvocationException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_TargetInvocationException...

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me:

Upgrade to [version 531](http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/ravendb) as [recommended by Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/136193/the-required-infrastructure-frees-you-from-infrastructure-decisions#comment13)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 531 build fixed this error.
Read more about it at [RavenDB's google group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/b7888a3ae7223988)